# Embedded data in Qualtrics showing up in the 'Data & Analysis' tab, but is not showing up for participants

Tags: javascript, survey, qualtrics

So I have a bit of JS in my Qualtrics survey that takes the response to a question, and if that response is not empty, it will embed the participant’s response (to be called later in the survey).  If they don’t enter anything, I have made it print a string.  I have done this with the following:

```js
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnUnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page is unloaded*/
    var tboxID= "QR~"+this.questionId;
    var hometownStr = document.getElementById(tboxID).value;

    Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('hometownStr',hometownStr);

    if(!hometownStr || 0 === hometownStr.length)
    {
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData('hometownStr', "your hometown"); 
    }
});
```

After the block this question is in [I have embedded the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlvt4.png).

So, let's say I am asked the question (in which the JS is embedded): *What is your hometown?*  I either answer that my hometown is (for example) "Paisley", or I leave it blank.  If I **don't** answer the question, the next question will say *This is a person from **your hometown***.  If I 
**do** answer the question, it *should* print: *This is a person from Paisley*.

**However**, the latter example *does not print* "Paisley" ([it prints nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1gbr.png)).  FYI, the former example works fine.

The strange thing is that, though "Paisley" is not printed in the survey, [*it comes out in the final data*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovPwT.png) (found in the Data & Analysis tab).

*Note*: I am calling the embedded data by `${e://Field/hometownStr}`.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?  Thanks in advance for any help; please tell me I am stupid and overlooking something major, and this isn't a bug in Qualtrics...

FYI, this code has worked in the past, so I don't think it's an issue with the code.  I refactored some of the questions and blocks and it just stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the survey flow embedded data block **BEFORE** the block where the JS sets it.

EDIT:
I noticed you are using addOnUnload.  Use addOnPageSubmit instead.

Comment: Oh my goodness, that works, thank you ever so much.  Why does this need to be embedded OnPageSubmit, not OnUnload?

Comment: With addOnUnload the page data (e.g., document.getElementById(tboxID).value;) is no longer available when the script runs.